# Generating 3D contours instead of 2D lines from a raster

Tags: qgis

I have difficulties generating 3D contour lines from a raster file in QGIS. It's a tif raster of an elevation model that I exported from a professor's ArcGIS project. I want to create contour lines in order to import them into SketchUP to design some engineering biological measures. Every time I use the Raster>Extract>Contours command, I only get 2D lines. I've already checked old forum entries and tried a couple of solutions, but so far nothing's worked out.

What could the problem possibly be?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to extract Z-values from your raster, and attach them to the contour lines you have just obtained.

(1) You have a raster and contour lines. (Make sure you have elevation attribute like `ELEV` in your line shapefile).
[image]

(2) Next, activate **GRASS v.drape** which you can find in the Processing Toolbox `GRASS GIS 7 | Vector`.

[image]

- `Input vector layer` : Your contour layer.
- `Elevation raster...` : Your raster.
- `WHERE conditions of SQL...` : You cannot leave it blank. Hence please add any conditions you can think of. In this case I set `"ELEV" < 100` so that I can select everything.
- `Vector Z for unknown height`: I set 1000 which was reasonably out of my value range.

(3) Running this will produce a new line layer named `3D vector`. You can check it by `Identify Features` tool, which gives you `Closest vertex Z` information.

[image]

(4) Do not forget export the (3D vector) as a new shapefile. Default setting will automatically keep the Z-dimension, but it is still better to double check Geometry type while saving.

---

**EDIT**

[image]

Just to add; if you import the 3D-contour and your raster into SAGA GIS, you can use 3D viewer to visually check your output.

Comment: You, Sir or Madam, have seriously saved my life! Thank you so much! I had some initial troubles installing GRASS on my Mac, but now it all worked out. :)

Comment: @vindobonensis It's my pleasure. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Try using QGIS 3.0, and run the contour algorithm. Check under advanced options and tick "Produce 3D vector".